# RewriteRule not working asa expected .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok, so here's my RewriteRule:

`RewriteRule ^books/book-([0-9]+)/(.*[^/])$/? authors/book-$1/$2 [R=301,L]`

so if someone goes to `www.example.com/books/book-5/some-book-title`, they are redirected to `www.example.com/authors/book-5/some-book-title`. This bit works fine.

However, the problem I have is this:
`www.example.com/books/book-5/some-book-title/still-more-stuff/still/more/stuff`
it will forward to `www.example.com/authors/book-5/some-book-title/still-more-stuff/still/more/stuff`.

I want it to stop after `www.example.com/books/book-5/some-title/` <- It should stop here!!!

It should not allow more parameters after the `/some-title/` <- or it should disregard them.

How can I achieve this? Only grab the first parameter `/some-title/`, otherwise throw a 404?  I thought that by putting the `[^/]` bit, it would stop when it found a forward `/`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteRule ^books/(book-\d+/[^/]+) authors/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Problem is actually presence of `.*` in your regex.

Comment: ok, but now, if I want to do the same for `books/book-1/title/more stuff`, i tried `RewriteRule ^books/(book-\d+/[^/]+) books/$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]` and I get internal server errors 500

Comment: But why do you have `book/$1` on RHS also? Should it not be `authors/$1`?

Comment: sorry, I meant authors, so `/authors/book-1/title/extra/stuff/` is still broken. what do i need to do to make sure that `/authors/book-1/title/` <- stops here

Comment: For that you can add a rule: `RewriteRule ^authors/(book-\d+/[^/]+)/.+$ authors/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]` below my suggested rule.